# <<>> Operator meaning in Athena SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, amazon-athena

What does the following statement means in AWS Athena SQL?

```
where column <<>>'Value'
```

Also what is the translation for <<= and >>= from AWS Athena SQL to BigQuery SQL? Following are the statements from AWS Athena:

```
where column <<= 3 and column2 >>= 2
```

Comment: Not finding those comparison operators in the official documentation.  Can you try some sample queries with different data types that return something unexpected?

Comment: Where did you find this?  If in documentation, some things are 'rubrics' and not literally to be copied, but just guessing... or could be combo of XML and SQL

Answer (score 0):

Athena doesn't support <<>>, <<= or >>=, but does support <> (not equal to), <= (less than or equal to) and >= (greater than or equal to). The bigquery also supports <>, <= and >=.